# How to delete spaces of grep search result?

Tags: regex, grep, spaces

I managed to find a pattern using Gnu grep 2.5.4 (OS is Windows 7)

What grep returns looks like:

```
Word1                         ( 1.22 )
Word2  ( -111.999 )
Word3 ( 123 )
```

So between end of the word and the bracket '(' always a various number of spaces is there.
Can I use grep to eliminate all spaces or all spaces but 1, so se result will look like:

```
Word1( 1.22 )
Word2( -111.999 )
Word3( 123 )
```

or (better)

```
Word1 ( 1.22 )
Word2 ( -111.999 )
Word3 ( 123 )
```

(Spaces within the brackets () may or may not be removed, this dosn' matter)
Do I need additional tools like sed or others?
I'm looking for a command line tool, so no text-editors search & replace can do this job.

Thanks for any hint!

Answer (score 3):

You can use pipe your result to `sed`:

```
some_command | sed 's/[[:blank:]]*(/ (/'

Word1 ( 1.22 )
Word2 ( -111.999 )
Word3 ( 123 )
```

Instead of `grep` you may consider using `awk` also:

```
awk '/Word/{sub(/[[:blank:]]*\(/, " (")} 1' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply Pipe your result to `tr` command.

```
your_grep_command | tr -s ' '
```

`tr -s ' '` : It will squeeze multiple spaces to one on each line.

Ex:

```
$ echo "Word1                         ( 1.22 )" | tr -s ' '
Word1 ( 1.22 )
```